# Condition in class

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, background-color, highlight, sourceforge-appscript

I am working on a project of automating sending emails based on html template from google sheet data using Appscript.

Below code worked for me

```
<td class="<?= r1 == "No" ? 'red-bg' : 'green-bg' ?>"><?= r1 ?></td>
```

I want to add another color parameter. If r1 is equal to "Partial" turn to amber color.

Appreciate your help

Comment: `<td class="<?= r1 == "No" ? 'red-bg' : r1 == "Partial" ? 'amber-bg' : 'green-bg' ?>"><?= r1 ?></td>`

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags, or explain how your problem is directly related to the tags you've used

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` operator is called the ternary operator. You can nest them but it is not very clear. For example:

```js
<td class="<?=
  r1 == "No" ? 'red-bg' :
  r1 == "Partial" ? 'amber-bg' :
 'green-bg'
?>"><?= r1 ?></td>
```

Otherwise, you can extract this logic to a function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can chain the conditional but you could try this:

`<td class="<?= r1 == "No" ? 'red-bg' : r1 == "Partial" ? 'amber' : 'green-bg' ?>"`

Comment: It's best to use parentheses to make the grouping obvious.